# Computing Probability

Tags: probability

Suppose we have two boxes containing $10$ balls of two colors (red and white).  Box $1$ contains $4$ red and $6$ white balls while Box $2$ has $3$ white and $7$ red balls.  Suppose three balls were selected (one at a time or without replacement)  from one box (we do not know which). What is the probability of drawing

a) $3$ white balls?
b) $2$ red balls and $1$ white ball?

Comment: Shall we select one box first? That is are both boxes "equally likely"? If not I think the problem is just to select from 11 red balls and total balls we have are 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a 1/2 chance that box 1 and 1/2 chance that box 2 is selected.
2. There are 6x5x4/3!=20 ways to draw 3 white balls from 6 white balls.
3. There are 10x9x8/3!=120 ways to draw 3 balls from 10 balls.
4. There is a 20/120x1/2=1/12 chance to draw 3 white balls from box 1.
5. There is 1 way to draw 3 white balls from 3 white balls.
6. There is a 1/120x1/2=1/240 chance to draw 3 white balls from box 2.
7. There is a 1/12+1/240=20/240+1/240=21/240=7/80 chance to draw 3 white balls from one of the boxes.

(This is only for a)

Answer (score 1):

The basic step is to calculate the number of different combinations of $3$ balls there are in a box that meet the requirements.

Suppose that I wanted the probability of drawing $2$ white balls and $1$ red ball. If I’m drawing from Box $1$, that means getting $2$ of the $6$ white balls and $1$ of the $4$ red balls. There are $\binom62=15$ ways to choose $2$ things out of a set of $6$, and there are $\binom41=4$ ways to choose one thing out of a set of $4$, so there are $15\cdot4=60$ different sets of $3$ balls that we could draw from Box $1$ and get $2$ white balls and $1$ red one. Similarly, there are $\binom32\binom71=3\cdot7=21$ ways to draw $2$ white balls and $1$ red one from Box $2$. Thus, there are altogether $60+21=81$ different sets of $3$ balls that we could draw that would meet our requirements.

Assuming that the boxes are equally likely to be picked, all sets of $3$ balls from one box are equally likely. There are $\binom{10}3=120$ different sets of $3$ balls that you can form from a set of $10$ balls, so there are $120$ different sets of $3$ balls that I could draw from Box $1$, and there are another $120$ sets that I could draw from Box $2$. Thus, there are altogether $120+120=240$ equally likely outcomes when I draw $3$ balls from one box, and $81$ of them have the desired composition. The probability of getting $2$ white balls and $1$ red one is therefore $$\frac{81}{240}=\frac{27}{80}=0.3375\;.$$

Now try to use this problem as a model for solving your two problems.

Comment: Thanks! I am actually puzzled with this part of the problem: Suppose three balls were selected (one at a time or without replacement) from one box (we do not know which).                              Does this mean :each time we draw a ball, it's either from Box 1 or Box 2"? For example, one possible outcome might R_1R_2R_1 which means the first ball is from Box 1, the second from Box 2, third from Box 1... Am I right? or, the three balls were drawn from one box alone?

Comment: @user99305: That can’t be right. It should probably read $R_1R_2R_3$, where the subscripts merely identify different red balls in one of the boxes.

Comment: Thank you, Brian M. Scott!

Comment: @user99305: You’re welcome!